# PHP code is shown without executing code when input is taken from a form field of html

Tags: php, html, eclipse, aptana

It is all good when I use notepad++. I get the expected result beautifully.

Recently, I started using Eclipse with Aptana Studio 3 plugins for taking the benefit of different code completion, templates, debugging, etc. I use Eclipse for PHP and Aptana plugins for html. When I execute only PHP script with Eclipse I get the results fine, but when I get input from html FORM field and have it processed with PHP script, I find that the raw code of PHP is shown on the browser without executing it. I don't know what configuration I need to change, or what I should do.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but maybe you should take a look at http://www.wampserver.com/en/. Wamp server is an easy to install application with which you can host websites locally. This way you could test your PHP code without the need of an IDE to run the files.

Comment: I think you are not saving your file where you should save them(like htdocs for w/xampp) but in default eclipse workspace.